# To get tar filename of package from the package name

Tags: arch-linux

How can we the name of tar package file (in cache dir.) from a package name ?

```
$ pacman -Q
```

...

or

```
$ pacman -F
```

...

to the complete correct CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither. You want to query the remote repository with `-S` (the "sync DB"), not the local DB which is not involved with the .pkg files:

```bash
expac -S %f "$pkgname"
```

```bash
pacman -Sp "$pkgname" | sed 's|.*/||'
```